# Access to website data from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scripting, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have an extension, and i want it do followings:

1. when user double clik and select a word, detect word
2. Do somthings on word, and show result on small interactive page like tooltip

I looking for something like [Google Dictionary extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja)

May anyone help me? what should i do ?

Thanks in advance. Morteza

Comment: If you want to "do something like <other extension>", just take a look at their source code. Install the [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin/) extension to easily do it (view source with one click).

Comment: most js codes are min, and very difficult to underestant

Comment: The extension linked above automatically beautifies the code. Some code remains relatively hard to comprehend, even after beautifying though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. its very usefull.
is there any tools like above extension to beautifies min.js code, out of extension places. too

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When text is selected, the selected text will be shown in an alert window. A good starting point....

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Selecty thingy",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Selecty thingy",  
    "browser_action": {
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "*://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js","content_script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

**content_script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').mouseup(function() {
        var selectedText = getSelectedText();
        if(selectedText > ''){
            alert(selectedText);
        }
    });

    function getSelectedText() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
            if(selection.trim() > ''){
                return selection;
            }
        } else if (document.selection) {
            var selection = document.selection.createRange().text;
            if(selection.trim() > ''){
                return selection;
            }
        }
        return '';
    } });
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReK24/) showing the functionality outside of a chrome extension...